# ORDER BY date bugs

Tags: mysql

I know there's some of those questions on SO already, but I can't find the correct answer.

I'm trying to ORDER by a date that is formatet like this: 01-01-1999. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT id, header, date FROM table ORDER BY date DESC
```

I'm getting 4 rows which seems okay, (They are the same) but then I get some odd results further on.

The fields are VARCHAR(); - what field should it be to store 01-01-1999 formats in?

The odd results is that I'm getting 4x30-08-2012.. And then lots of old dates, but then suddenly there's 2 records with 13-09-2012.

My question is: How come it's not sorting them: 2x13-09-2012 and then 4x30-08-2012 and then further on.

**UPDATE**

The problem is solved. But still: What data-field would I use for my dates instead of VARCHAR?

Comment: What type is the `date` field? What are the odd results you mention? What is your actual question?

Comment: If you are able to change the table layout, use [`DATETIME` or `DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) for your date.

Comment: The field should be DATE. You can use MySQL or PHP functions to format it however you want when outputting.

Comment: Rather than rely on someone to answer the question for you, why not read up on the differences between them and see which you think is more suitable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
SELECT id, header, date FROM table
ORDER BY str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC
```

See [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Lol, this worked. How come this worked, when 30-08-2012 doesn't work? :)

Comment: If you don't cast it to a date then it will be ordered alphabetical.

Comment: Oh, that's why. Pretty obvious actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

juergen has given an answer which basically involves the date being parsed each time. Two other alternatives suggest themselves though:

- Change your database schema so that the column is *already a date type* (e.g. [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)) rather than a string. Life is often a lot better when you make your database columns accurately represent the type of data you want to store in them.
- If you *really* need to store the data in string columns, consider changing the format to yyyy-MM-dd. That's a *naturally sortable* format, in that the "alphabetic" ordering is compatible with the "semantic" ordering of dates.

The first option is definitely preferrable IMO. This goes way beyond ordering, to:

- Validation (well, hopefully; I gather MySQL is rather more forgiving of invalid data than I personally like, but...)
- Conversion: I'm not sure what the PHP support is like, but in general you should be able to send and receive date/time values to/from the database *without converting them into strings*, which removes error-prone conversions
- Clarity of purpose: give us much help as possible to anyone examining the database. Whatever you know about the data, put it into the schema. If you store everything as varchar regardless of whether it's text, numeric or date/time data, you might as well say "Well, it's just some *stuff*"

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store dates in strings is 'YYYY-MM-DD'. MySQL has native format for dates - [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).